# C# read web RSS href, can not find node<a>

Tags: c#, rss, html-parsing

my program need to get the  RSS link then go to read the rss.

I found when i parse to  layer `<div id="titleRSS_7224" class="rss"></div>`
the `<a>`inside of it gone.

i'm using the `HtmlAgilityPack`

i can see the`<a>` from the google chrome

```
<div id="titleRSS_7224" class="rss">
<a title="RSS 2.0" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="/rss/media/bz0xMiZmbHBsPTIxMjEzNjYsMjAsODQwLDAmZng9.rss"></a>
</div>
```

my code is:

```
HtmlDocument temNode= new HtmlDocument();
string temStr = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(longPath).InnerHtml;
temNode.LoadHtml(page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(longPath).InnerHtml);
```

then I check both `temStr`  and `temNode`, the `<a>` is no in there.

i get another idea that is to do:

```
 HtmlNode temNode = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@title='RSS 2.0']");
```

this works.

but just want to know why the first method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you just select the single node instead of the innerhtml youll be able to enumerate the childnodes?

Just spitballing though as im not familiar with that api.